# Clone div if it overflows parent bottom to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an A4-print template for WP, and I want it to dynamically create new pages when content overflows. So my plan is to target each child div that has an offset greater than the parents `.top + height();`. Note: I use the `self.css('color','red');` to check that the function is working.

With this code below I get an error:

> copyCon is not defined

```
function newPage() {
    if ($(this).height() > a4Height) {
        offObject.each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            var offObjectWrap = self.parent().parent().parent('.docWrap');
            var wrapBottom = offObjectWrap.offset().top + offObjectWrap.height();
            var selfPos = self.offset().top + self.height();
            if (selfPos > wrapBottom) {
                var copyCon = $(this).clone();
            } else {
                self.css('color', 'red');
            }
        });

        var copyFooter = $(".offerFooter").clone();
        $(this).parent().parent().after('<section id="page4" class="offerPage docWrap pageTwo clearfix"><div class="docPad clearfix"><div class="docCon clearfix">' + copyCon.html() + '</div></div><div class="offerFooter clearfix">' + copyFooter.html() + "</div></section>");
    }
}

docCon.each(newPage);
```

Comment: You define `copyCon` within the `each()` anonymous function, therefore it's out of scope when you use it in the `after()` method.

Comment: Ok, so how should I define it instead? Without the `each()`?

Comment: If you want to access it out of each() define it before like `var copyCon` and in the each loop simply assign value to it without `var`. Not sure that this will work as you expected though.

Comment: I actually tried that, and the result wasn't any different...

Comment: If the copyCon still wasn't defined, then it never had value assigned in each() loop.